# cannot parse JSON object: "[$http:baddata] Data must be a valid JSON object"

Tags: javascript, json

Here is the outptut that I have and trying to get jobStatus inside jobStatus object. its throwing me cannot parse json object

```
var x = 
    { "jobStatus": 
      { "jobStatus"   : "COMPLETED"
      , "jobType"     : "xyz"
      , "scheduleType": "Immediate"
      , "startTime"   : "Oct 10, 2019 2:20:45 AM"
      , "endTime"     : "Oct 10, 2019 2:20:48 AM"
      , "Time"        : "Oct 10, 2019 2:20:40 AM"
      , "phase"       : "null"
      , "submittedBy" : "random"
      } 
    }
```

code I'm using

Error :

> [$http:baddata] Data must be a valid JSON object. Received: "COMPLETED". Parse error: "{}"
>   https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$http/baddata?p0=COMPLETED&p1=%7B%7D```

```
var y = JSON.parse(x);
var status = y.jobStatus;
var y = JSON.parse(status);
var z = y.jobStatus;
Console.log(z)
```

Comment: `x` is not JSON, it's a JavaScript object. You don't need to parse it.

Comment: It would be JSON if you put quotes around it.

Comment: `x` is not JSON. JSON is always *a string* - it's a text serialisation format. What you have is a plain object, you can just use it as is.

Comment: You don't require `var y = JSON.parse(x);` instead you can use `var y = x;`

Comment: And you don't need `JSON.parse(status)` either.

Comment: I'm trying to convert into json snd my output should look like ```COMPLETED```

Comment: ```[$http:baddata] Data must be a valid JSON object. Received: "COMPLETED". Parse error: "{}"
https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$http/baddata?p0=COMPLETED&p1=%7B%7D```

Comment: You don't need a conversion. It's already a javascript object literal.

Comment: try - console.log(x['jobStatus']['jobStatus'])

Answer (score 0):

JSON or javascript object you don't need to parse anything

```js
var x = 
    { "jobStatus": 
      { "jobStatus"   : "COMPLETED"
      , "jobType"     : "xyz"
      , "scheduleType": "Immediate"
      , "startTime"   : "Oct 10, 2019 2:20:45 AM"
      , "endTime"     : "Oct 10, 2019 2:20:48 AM"
      , "Time"        : "Oct 10, 2019 2:20:40 AM"
      , "phase"       : "null"
      , "submittedBy" : "random"
      } 
    } 

let y = x.jobStatus.scheduleType
console.log( y )
// or
let z = x['jobStatus']['jobType'] 
console.log( z )

/* ------- */
var A = 
    { jobStatus: 
      { jobStatus   : "COMPLETED"
      , jobType     : "xyz"
      , scheduleType: "Immediate"
      , startTime   : "Oct 10, 2019 2:20:45 AM"
      , endTime     : "Oct 10, 2019 2:20:48 AM"
      , Time        : "Oct 10, 2019 2:20:40 AM"
      , phase       : "null"
      , submittedBy : "random"
      } 
    } 
let B = A.jobStatus.jobType
console.log( B )
// or
let C = A['jobStatus']['scheduleType'] 
console.log( C )
```